# Sum of all rows based on specific column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
Index  Parameters   A    B   C   D   E
1      Apple        1    2   3   4   5
2      Banana       2    4   5   3   5
3      Potato       3    5   3   2   1
4      Tomato       1    1   1   1   1
5      Pear         4    5   5   4   3
```

**I want to add all the rows which has Parameter values as "Apple" , "Banana" and "Pear".**

Output:

```
Index  Parameters   A    B   C   D   E
1      Apple        1    2   3   4   5
2      Banana       2    4   5   3   5
3      Potato       3    5   3   2   1
4      Tomato       1    1   1   1   1
5      Pear         4    5   5   4   3
6      Total        7    11  13  11  13
```

**My Effort**:

1. `df[:,'Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)` -- Works but I want specific values only and not all
2. Tried by the index in my case `1,2 and 5` but in my original df the index can vary from time to time and hence rejected that solution.

Saw various answers on SO but none of them could solve my problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is create index by `Parameters` column and select rows for `sum` and last convert index to column:

```
L = ["Apple" , "Banana" , "Pear"]
df = df.set_index('Parameters')
df.loc['Total'] = df.loc[L].sum()
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Parameters  A   B   C   D   E
0      Apple  1   2   3   4   5
1     Banana  2   4   5   3   5
2     Potato  3   5   3   2   1
3     Tomato  1   1   1   1   1
4       Pear  4   5   5   4   3
5      Total  7  11  13  11  13
```

Or add new row for filtered rows by membership with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and overwrite last added value by `Total`:

```
last = len(df)
df.loc[last] = df[df['Parameters'].isin(L)].sum()
df.loc[last, 'Parameters'] = 'Total'
print (df)
      Parameters  A   B   C   D   E
Index                              
1          Apple  1   2   3   4   5
2         Banana  2   4   5   3   5
3         Potato  3   5   3   2   1
4         Tomato  1   1   1   1   1
5          Total  7  11  13  11  13
```

Another similar solution is filtering all columns without first and add value in one element list:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Total'] + df.iloc[df['Parameters'].isin(L).values, 1:].sum().tolist()
```